# Какой контейнер позволяет выполнить поиск элемента по ключу?

Tags: java, поиск

Какой контейнер позволяет выполнить поиск элемента по ключу?

Comment: без указания целевого языка сложно сказать, но в любом случае это скорее всго будет словарь/мапа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.На Java,это будет Map?